# Guided Access and push

Tags: ios, push, guided-access

Is there a way to let my app receive push-messages, when it is in Guided Access?
We have an app allways running Guided Access, but we need to send messages to it.

Additionally, is there a way to remove all apps so you only have access to one or more and no settings?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I think it's able to receive push notification in Guided Access. But if you want to remove all apps etc, you have to use MDM.